# WinForms Assoicating a variable with a control

Tags: winforms, data-binding

I've just written a program in win forms and c# that replicates the game "Yahtzee". Although, my code did the job, and the game worked well. I felt like the code was really sloppy. The main part that bugged me was that I had five buttons on my form, that represented each yahtzee dice. when you click on a dice it means you wanted to save that dice for the next roll. so I had five different variables that stored whether the dice is saved or not (bool save1, save2, save3, save4, save5). I ended up having to use if and else if statements to decide what save button was going to be changed. I would like to know a way to somehow associate the cooresponding variable to each button so the code is much more consice and easy to read. This is similar to the code I was using, where the function below is called when either dice is clicked.

```
dice_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e){ 
   if (sender == dice1){
      save1 = true;
   }else if (sender == dice2){
      save2 = true;
   }else if (sender == dice3){
      save3 = true;
   }else if (sender == dice4){
      save4 = true;
   }else if (sender == dice5){
      save5 = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: You could use a [Dictionary<Buttton, bool>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx), with the Button as the Key, and the Boolean as the Value; then you get/set the value using the "sender" parameter in the click handler.

Comment: @Idle_Mind This seems like a great idea, could you maybe write some code, so that I can understand it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You could use a Dictionary, with the Button as the Key,
>   and the Boolean as the Value; then you get/set the value using the
>   "sender" parameter in the click handler. – Idle_Mind 19 hours ago
>
> @Idle_Mind This seems like a great idea, could you maybe write some code, so that I can understand it better – cj32 22 mins ago

Here's some example code to play with using the Dictionary approach:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Dictionary<Button, bool> saveBtn = new Dictionary<Button, bool>();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add initial entries and set them to false
        saveBtn.Add(dice1, false);
        saveBtn.Add(dice2, false);
        saveBtn.Add(dice3, false);
        saveBtn.Add(dice4, false);
        saveBtn.Add(dice5, false);
    }

    private void dice_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button sourceBtn = (Button)sender;
        saveBtn[sourceBtn] = true; // set save state to true for that button

        // example code to reset all values to false:
        foreach(KeyValuePair<Button, bool> kvp in saveBtn)
        {
            saveBtn[kvp.Key] = false;
        }

        // example to find all the buttons that have been saved:
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Button, bool> kvp in saveBtn)
        {
            if (kvp.Value)
            {
                Button btn = kvp.Key;
                // do something with "btn"
                btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }

        // is dice3 saved?
        if (saveBtn[dice3])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("dice3 was saved");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the dice number in the `Tag` property of the buttons and use an array for the save states

```
bool[] save = new bool[5]; // Index range 0 to 4.

dice_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int diceNo = Int32.Parse(((Button)sender).Tag);
    save[diceNo - 1] = true;
}
```

If you numbered the dice and buttons starting with 0 instead of 1, the indexes and the numbers would match. Array indexes are always 0-based.

Comment: Wow I never thought to do this. Great idea thank you!